# Creating a new sub column in multiIndex, by dividing the other two sub columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'm getting an error when I try to create a new calculated column by dividing two numbers by the total sum (1+1/3+2+1+1).

The error is:
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

This is currently what I have:

```
lvl0           a                   b               
lvl1         bar       foo       bar       foo     
lvl2        fake real fake real fake real fake real
A0 B0 C0 D0    2    3    0    1    6    7    4    5
         D1   10   11    8    9   14   15   12   13
      C1 D0   18   19   16   17   22   23   20   21
         D1   26   27   24   25   30   31   28   29
      C2 D0   34   35   32   33   38   39   36   37
         D1   42   43   40   41   46   47   44   45
      C3 D0   50   51   48   49   54   55   52   53
         D1   58   59   56   57   62   63   60   61

first = dfmi['a', 'foo', 'fake'] + dfmi['a', 'bar', 'fake']
dfmi = dfmi.loc[:, ('a', 'Fake %', 'Fake Calculation')] = first.div(dfmi.sum(axis=1, level=0), level=0)
```

You should be able to copy and paste to test

```
# creating MultiIndex
def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A', 4),
                                        mklbl('B', 2),
                                        mklbl('C', 4),
                                        mklbl('D', 2)])


micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'foo', 'fake'),
                                       ('a', 'foo', 'real'),
                                       ('a', 'bar', 'fake'),
                                       ('a', 'bar', 'real'),
                                       ('b', 'foo', 'fake'),
                                       ('b', 'foo', 'real'),
                                       ('b', 'bar', 'fake'),
                                       ('b', 'bar', 'real'),
                                       ],
                                      names=['lvl0', 'lvl1', 'lvl2'])


dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns))
                     .reshape((len(miindex), len(micolumns))),
                    index=miindex,
                   columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

# My Code
first = dfmi['a', 'foo', 'fake'] + dfmi['a', 'bar', 'fake']
dfmi = dfmi.loc[:, ('a', 'Fake %', 'Fake Calculation')] = first.div(dfmi.sum(axis=1, level=0), level=0)
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
lvl0           a                            b               
lvl1         bar       foo                bar       foo     
lvl2        fake real fake real CALCULATE fake real fake real
A0 B0 C0 D0    2    3    0    1     33%    6    7    4    5
         D1   10   11    8    9     47%   14   15   12   13
      C1 D0   18   19   16   17     ETC   22   23   20   21
         D1   26   27   24   25     ETC   30   31   28   29
      C2 D0   34   35   32   33     ETC   38   39   36   37
         D1   42   43   40   41     ETC   46   47   44   45
      C3 D0   50   51   48   49     ETC   54   55   52   53
         D1   58   59   56   57     ETC   62   63   60   61
```

The calculate column is just (fake+fake)/(fake+real+fake+real) in the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
df.sum(level=[0,2],axis=1).loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'fake']].div(df.sum(level=0,axis=1),level=0,axis=0)
```

Comment: That worked and calculated it but i'm having trouble putting it back into the dataframe, I'm getting NaN for the column when i put it back in.



`dfmi.loc[:, ('a', 'Fake %', 'Fake Calculation')] = dfmi.sum(level=[0,2],axis=1).loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'fake']].div(dfmi.sum(level=0,axis=1),level=0,axis=0)`